# Google Sheets - How to check if ANY values in a column are equal

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that I am using to keep track of my work order numbers and invoice numbers, and I want to implement a conditional format that will check all the values in those columns, and highlight the offending cells if there are any duplicate order or invoice numbers. Any help here would be appreciated.

For example, I have a column of 400 work order numbers. I want to run a check that will compare all of the values to every other value in the column, and if there is a work order number of 422509 in P7 and P390, highlight both P7 and P390 in red.

Comment: Please share the code you are currently using so that we may better help you. Consider a full [mcve].

Comment: @AndrewFan I do not have any existing code on those columns. It's manual input of the values, and the only thing that I plan on having code-wise is this duplicate check that I am trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

Please select ColumnP and try a custom formula of:

```
=countif(P:P,P1)>1
```